# Looking for a way to redirect all trafic from one domain to another

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect www.demo.com to www.example.com. I've tried all the examples below. They work to a point, but only if the user types in www.demo.com, then they're redirect to www.example.com

The problem is if the user finds www.demo.com/contact-us in a search, the redirects don't work.

I need a wildcard/blanket redirect so no matter what page someone tries to visit on 
www.demo.com it will redirect to www.demo.com

None of the examples below do this.

*Note: I have tried this separately (!) I've not used them all at the same time :)*

Hope someone can help.

```
This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain
Redirect 301 / http://example.com


RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com [R=301]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>



RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?demo\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```